# Regex for excluding apostrophe(') character

Tags: regex

I need a regex that will include all the alphabets, numbers and even all special characters except apostrophe(').

The below regular expression will work only for numbers and alphabets.

```
/^[a-z A-Z 0-9 ]*$/
```

But I need a regular expression which includes all the special characters except apostrophe (').

Answer (score 6):

You can try to use this regex:

```
[^']
```

This Regex will match every character except apostrophe

Answer (score 6):

The regular expression for "any character other than an apostrophe" would be: `[^']`.

So a regular expression that will match a string as long as it does not have an apostrophe would be:  `/^[^']*$/`